# Is artificial sweetener (Splenda, Stevia) pre-cooked? (Making Coffee on Shabbat)

Tags: halacha, shabbat, food, cooking-bishul

When making a coffee on Shabbat, is one allowed to put the artificial sweetener, such as Splenda or Stevia, into the cup and then add the hot water from Kli Rishon?

If the sweetener is pre-cooked, then this procedure would not be not a problem. On the other hand, if it's not pre-cooked (or heated considerably to a point that makes it "Mevushal"), one would have to add the sweetener after putting the water in the cup. So, are these sweeteners considered "pre-cooked" or not?

Comment: Stevia comes in various forms. I assum eyou refer to the common powdered form. I think it comes in a liquid / dropper form, which might be less problematic as I think that form contains alcohol which prob. would not cook as easily.

Answer (score 5):

Partial answer:

[OU](http://www.onlysimchas.com/news/17797/ou-rules-splenda-is-considered-cooked-can-be-used-on-shabbos) rules that Splenda is pre-cooked. However it recommends using a kli sheni, not a kli rishon.